# Erro RSelenium - Selenium message:Java heap space

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Olá, estou tentando fazer um scraping do http://acervo.estadao.com.br/ usando o RSelenium, porque a página só gera as informações no html quando é carregada no browser.

Bem quando acontece isso não sei fazer de outra forma que não seja com o RSelenium. Mas quando o loop executa cerca de 250 vezes, ele encerra e aparece a mensagem abaixo:

> Selenium message:Java heap space
>
> Erro:      Summary: UnknownError       Detail: An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command.     Further Details: run
>   errorDetails method

---

> informação da secão
>
> R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
>   (64-bit) Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6
>
> Matrix products: default BLAS:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
>   LAPACK:
>   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
>
> locale: [1]
>   pt_BR.UTF-8/pt_BR.UTF-8/pt_BR.UTF-8/C/pt_BR.UTF-8/pt_BR.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] wdman_0.2.2     magrittr_1.5
>   rvest_0.3.2     xml2_1.1.1      [5] httr_1.3.1      XML_3.98-1.9
>   RSelenium_1.7.1

Answer (score 2):

Problemas relacionas a heap estão ligados a memória, neste caso a memória que o java alocou, quando tente achar o comando para compilar com mais memória, ou se isto não for compilado tente achar um modo para seu programa usar mais memória do que já est asendo fornecida.